# Why is this code printing a line after reading one line of content

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

```
file = 'pi'
with open(file) as object:
    for line in object:
        print(line)
```

The file content includes the first 30 digits of pi, and I don't understand why it is printing a line after reading a particular line. As in, how can print(line) actually print a line?

The contents of the file are henceforth:

```
3.1415926535
8979323846
2643383279
```

And this is the output:

```
3.1415926535

8979323846

2643383279
```

Answer (score 0):

Because by default, print add a newline after a print, you can change this by adding the end parameter to your print statement :

`print(line, end='')`

Answer (score 0):

Print function takes many parameters. One relevant here is `end`. Default value is `'\n'`

try `print(line, end='')`

Answer (score 0):

This is because each row in your datafile is appended with a newline character, `\n`. If you want to remove this from your line, you can do

```
line = line.rstrip()
```

If you want to print without the newline character, change the `args` to `print` as

```
print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The line strings that you are looping include a newline character at the end (`"\n"`), and `print` also adds a newline after the call, so you have two. Instead, you can strip the newline character before printing:

```py
file = 'pi'
with open(file) as object:
    for line in object:
        print(line.strip("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation provided [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed
> by end. sep, end, file, and flush, if present, must be given as
> keyword arguments.

If no parameters are provided, `end` parameter takes "\n" by default.

So, you could print the lines like:

```
print(line, end='')
```